# Метод afterTextChanged вызывается после изменения конфигурации

Tags: android, android-edittext

В методе `onCreate` Активити я связываю `EditText` c `TextWatcher`-ом:

```
etTitle.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {}

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {}

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "afterTextChanged");
                ...
            }
        });
```

Можно ли как-нибудь разграничить ситуации, когда метод `afterTextChanged` вызывается действительно после изменения текста в `EditText`, а когда этот метод вызывается просто после поворота экрана?

Comment: Как вариант можно вешать слушателя в onResume, а в onPause ремувить его

Comment: @RomanK., да, спасибо, помогло! Оформите как ответ, приму обязательно)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вешайте слушателя в `onResume`, а в `onPause` ремувьте его